# Removing polygons from exported RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, mesh

I have the following code that runs a RegionPlot

```
Clear[Rg3, SetRg3, Ig3, SetIg3, κ1, Setκ1, Γ, SetΓ, κ2, Setκ2, g1, Setg1, g2, Setg2, r1]
Setκ1 = 1; SetΓ = 0.01; Setκ2 = 20;
r1 = RegionPlot[SetRg3 = 0; SetIg3 = 0; 
NMG3 = {{-Γ/
  2, -I*g1, -I*Rg3 + Ig3}, {-I*g1, -κ1/
  2, -I*g2}, {-I*Rg3 - Ig3, - I*g2, -κ2/2}} /. {Rg3 -> 
  SetRg3, Ig3 -> SetIg3, κ1 -> 
  Setκ1, Γ -> 
  SetΓ, κ2 -> Setκ2, g1 -> Setg1, 
 g2 -> Setg2};
EigensysNMG3 = 
Eigensystem[NMG3, Cubics -> True]; {Chop[
Min[{((Abs[
       Normalize[
         EigensysNMG3[[2]][[1]]] /. {κ1 -> 
          Setκ1, Γ -> 
          SetΓ, κ2 -> Setκ2, 
         g3 -> Setg3}]).Transpose[{{1, 0, 0}}]), ((Abs[
       Normalize[
         EigensysNMG3[[2]][[2]]] /. {κ1 -> 
          Setκ1, Γ -> 
          SetΓ, κ2 -> Setκ2, 
         g3 -> Setg3}]).Transpose[{{1, 0, 0}}]), ((Abs[

       Normalize[
         EigensysNMG3[[2]][[3]]] /. {κ1 -> 
          Setκ1, Γ -> 
          SetΓ, κ2 -> Setκ2, 
         g3 -> Setg3}]).Transpose[{{1, 0, 0}}])}] >= 
 RankedMax[{((Abs[
        Normalize[
          EigensysNMG3[[2]][[1]]] /. {κ1 -> 
           Setκ1, Γ -> 
           SetΓ, κ2 -> Setκ2, 
          g3 -> Setg3}]).Transpose[{{1, 0, 0}}])[[1]], ((Abs[
        Normalize[
          EigensysNMG3[[2]][[2]]] /. {κ1 -> 
           Setκ1, Γ -> 
           SetΓ, κ2 -> Setκ2, 
          g3 -> Setg3}]).Transpose[{{1, 0, 0}}])[[1]], ((Abs[
        Normalize[
          EigensysNMG3[[2]][[3]]] /. {κ1 -> 
           Setκ1, Γ -> 
           SetΓ, κ2 -> Setκ2, 
          g3 -> Setg3}]).Transpose[{{1, 0, 0}}])[[1]]}, 
  2]]}, {Setg1, 0.01, 10}, {Setg2, 0.01, 12}, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.35]], PlotRangePadding -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None]
```

which generates
[image]

Now I need it to be in vector format so I did `Export["r1.pdf", r1]`. However, there are these polygons/triangles that shows up and it becomes really inconvenient for me to when doing post editing on Inkscape. I have included the zoomed in example below
[image]

As one can see, there are faint lines of triangles that are tiled in there. Removing them is what I'm trying to do.

Now I understand that this seems to be a common question upon Googling. However, none of the solutions worked for me in that it did not achieve what I want (namely, have it to be still vectorized, minus the triangles) or they were too difficult for me to understand and implement. For example, I have tried

```
Export["r1.pdf", 
Show[r1, 
Prolog -> {Opacity[0], Texture[{{{0, 0, 0, 0}}}], 
VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
Polygon[{{0, 0}, {.1, 0}, {.1, .1}}]}]
]
```

which seems to do the trick. However, I need to post process it on Inkscape. But doing

```
Export["r1.svg", 
Show[r1, 
Prolog -> {Opacity[0], Texture[{{{0, 0, 0, 0}}}], 
VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
Polygon[{{0, 0}, {.1, 0}, {.1, .1}}]}]
]
```

Doesn't seem to vectorize it properly (while removing the triangles). I still see course pixels upon opening `r1.svg` on Inkscape.

Appreciate any help that I can get. Thanks for reading.

Comment: You need only the boundary right? The vector graphics programs can typically fill it on their own. So try to export `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[r1]` instead.

Comment: do you get what you need if you export `r2 = r1 /. {EdgeForm[], d_, 
    p___} :> {EdgeForm[DeleteCases[_EdgeForm]@d], d, p}` instead of `r1`?